# Unable to add to Cart Class

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

I've just started playing around with the shopping cart class for CodeIgniter (version 2.1.4) and I've been following tutorials that help explain it. But for some reason I am unable to successfully add a a simple array to the cart.

Here is my implementation of the cart class:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cart extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent:: __construct();
}

public function index() {
    $nav["navigation"] = $this->getCategory->getCategories();

    $this->load->view("header");
    $this->load->view("scripts"); 
    $this->load->view("nav", $nav);
    $this->load->view("cart");
    $this->load->view("footer");
}

function add() {
    $data = array(
        "id"        => "42",
        "name"      => "pants",
        "quantity"  => 1,
        "price"     => 19.99,
        "options"   => array("size" => "medium")
    );

    $this->cart->insert($data);
    var_dump($this->cart->contents()); //This should output the array!

}

function show() {

    $cart = $this->cart->contents();
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($cart) . "</pre>"; //Nothing here either!

}

function update() {

    $this->cart->update($data);
    redirect(base_url()."cart");

}

function total() {

    echo $this->cart->total();

}

function remove() {

    $this->cart->update($data);  

}

function destroy() {

    $this->cart->destroy();

}
```

}

But if I go to the add function the var_dump just displays "array(0) { }". Same result if I navigate to the show function.

Here is my autoload config showing that I have autoloaded the cart library has been loaded:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array("database", "session", "cart");

$autoload['helper'] = array("html", "url", "form");
```

I know it's something really simple and obvious I'm missing, but right now I'm just left baffled. Any suggestions?

Comment: hey jesse - i luv CI, but the cart class has so many stupid issues. i wasted so much time trying to integrate it. its fine for a quick demo but if this is a production website - make your own table to hold the cart items and build out from there.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, yeah I am researching for a production website. I know there are other cart classes for CI, do you know anything about the alternatives like flexi-cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array key for `quantity` is named improperly. In the data your are inserting the quantity [must be named](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html) as `qty` for the data to be saved to the cart.

```
"qty"  => 1,
```

Comment: Thanks, got it one! Works fine now.