# Codeigniter Cart wrong cookie

Tags: codeigniter, session, cookies, cart

I embedded this example http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-build-a-shopping-cart-using-codeigniter-and-jquery/  to my shop.
I faced an issue that $total = $this->cart->total_items(); gets quantity value.
And if compare cookies from my site with cookie from example this is the difference:
my ...total_items"***;i:66;***s:10:"cart_total";i:5610;}}.....
original ...total_items***";s:1***:"1";s:10:"cart_total";s:4:"1499";...

So as you can see cookie stores wrong. I tried logging variables in Cart library but for this moment haven't caught problem. And I have another issue, as I think related with cookie I cannot add more than 7 items in cart. But I investigated this issue a bit, and mentioned only for helping.

Comment: I don't think thats the problem.  Why would the cookies be the same.  Do you actually understand the code or have you just copied and pasted it?

Comment: In general Cart is like black box so it wait an dedicated data and generate dedicated data for output. That is why cookie must be same format but not data. Why do you think that cookie must be different?

Comment: hi - start with this tutorial and use the included code sample - i know it works and he's a great teacher http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-shopping-cart/ THEN write your own because ci cart lib is not so great - see my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056107/unable-to-add-to-cart-class/19070589#19070589